# Resetting gcc's asm inline input

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

How to ask gcc to reset an asm inline input value? `%0` in the following example is not reset to `42` after the first loop. So when i = 1, `%0` value is still `0`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  asm("label: substract_immediate_value %0,%0,1;"
      "compare_immediate_value %0,0;"
      "branch_not_equal label"
      : /* no outputs */
      : /* input */ "r" (42));
```

Comment: What processor is this for? Anyway, using the proper processor instruction to set some value in some register. Usually a mnemonic something like `mov`, `move`, `set`, `let`...

Comment: Which architecture? ARM..?

Comment: You are lying to GCC about what you are doing: your outputs and discards sections are empty, yet you mutate register contents. You need to tell gcc that the subi will trash a register. So add a temporary either to the outputs or the discards section and use that for subi's output instead of %0.

Comment: @moonshadow I don't think I am lying to gcc, it should be taken as it is : here is an input value for my asm block. So it depends if "input" means input to asm() or to instructions (good question...). But yes, the solution you suggest (putting it as an input-output) is the one I use so far but it allocates a register outside this block for nothing. And there is no way (that I know) to say that an input is clobbered.

Comment: The constraints following the colons in the asm block describe your inputs, outputs and clobbers. Your asm block is a contract with GCC: you promise that registers / memory locations not mentioned will not change. Your routine breaks that contract: it makes no claims that it will alter registers, then alters %0. Declare a local variable, add it to your outputs or clobber list. This is the correct way. GCC is free to decide to reuse the register or not, as it sees fit. If you want to coerce it into writing a specific assembly sequence, just write that assembly sequence yourself instead.

Comment: @moonshadow How do you put a variable to the clobber list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this, but it looks right:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    int n = 42;
    asm("label: substract_immediate_value %0,%0,1;"
        "compare_immediate_value %0,0;"
        "branch_not_equal label"
        :  "+r" (n));
  }
```

I presume this is a simplified example, because I can't imagine why you wouldn't just code that in C. Indeed, it's a no-op.

Comment: Yes, I only show the problem here. I was hoping another solution but this is the one I use so far (and dislike).

Comment: What do you dislike about it? It tells the compiler exactly what it needs to know to produce the desired output. The extra variable *is* necessary because, as you've discovered, writing to a constant is not what you want.